# Jaspersoft mongo aggregation query use parameter in match expression to get one or all results

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have designed JasperReports report with MongoDB data source. See my mongodb pipeline query below:

```mongodb
{
   runCommand:{
        aggregate:"my_collection",
        pipeline:[
                    {$match :
                    {$and : [
                                { tenant_id: 1},    
                                { $or: [ { $P{Location}: -1 }, { location : $P{Location}} ] },
                 ]}},
                {
                $project : {
                            product_attribute_value : 1,
                            inventory_on_hand : 1   ,
                            unit_cost : 1
                        }
                },

                {
                                $group : {
                                            _id : "$product_attribute_value",
                                            itemsCount: { $sum : 1 },
                                            inventoryValue:{$multiply : ["$inventory_on_hand", "$unit_cost"] },
                                            }
                                }
                }                                                           
        ]
    }
}
```

I have a location parameter with corresponding input control as a dropdown. I want to group data based on change in location dropdown. The location dropdown has ALL as a default value. When user selects ALL then parameter value will be -1 and I want to get records for all locations. But `$P{Location}` is not a valid mongo field so it is not working.

I know other way, have a project stage before match and have a literal defined with value -1 and use that literal in match stage, but if I use project before match stage then it will fetch all data and then will apply match. This will degrade performance. I don't want to do this. I want to apply filters first and then pass filtered documents to pipeline stages.

Please suggest me an alternative.

Comment: `I have a location parameter with corresponding input control as a dropdown.` - Are you talking about JasperReports Server?

Comment: Yes, I am using JasperReports server for reports and mongodb as a database.